# Where can I find an algorithm for generating digital camouflage pattern?

Tags: c#, algorithm

[Here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/2/26/CadPatTW.jpg/300px-CadPatTW.jpg) is a sample of what I'm looking to reproduce.

I thought about tiling an image but that would create a detectable pattern.
I also thought about a random pattern using 4 or 5 colors but this is not a random pattern.

Thanks!

Comment: well i'm not sure exactly what you're looking for here. they way I would go about this type of problem is to create several images in the same style with no patterns around the edges (ie all images have brown edge so there's no cutoff) the randomly tile those images as your background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do:

1. choose a few colors for your camo
2. create a blank canvas
3. seed a number of points using your colors (change random pixels to a random color)
4. fill in the gaps using the algorithm below.

You want this to be random but you also want some clustering for those stripes/blobs in your example. So, by filling in the gaps from the seed points outwards, you can use the surrounding pixels to influence the color decision. If a pixel is surrounded by green, then it should be more likely to be green than yellow. So, for every pixel moving outwards from the seed points:

- Consider your surrounding (8, 24, etc) pixels and use those to determine the chances for each color. Each color gets assigned a range of numbers between 0 and 1 (For example, green might be .23 - .57). The sum of the ranges should include all numbers between 0 and 1.
- Use a random number generator to choose a number between 0 and 1. Whatever color range the number falls into is what color that pixel should be.
- Find an adjacent blank pixel, repeat.

Totally untested, but it works in my head? Haha.

EDIT And if you'd like the larger boxes that digital camo actually has (as opposed to single pixels) group the pixels into groups of 9, 16, 25, 36, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The military uses a fractal pattern called [MARPAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MARPAT), which I understand is highly effective compared to other known camo patterns. However, they have patented it, and I'm not aware of any way to find out the specifics.

Your best bet is probably [Perlin noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm), though I'm not sure how effective it would be as actual camouflage if you printed it out and tried to hide with it. You should be able to generate something that *looks* a lot like military camouflage, which is probably what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise)

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Mr E's answer, if you want to go the procedural route, look at various fractal algorithms.

Here's a map generator that uses erosion, I could imagine you layering several of those and maybe skewing things horizontally for your image: http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=5174.180

There's all sorts of other pattern generators - simulating termites, forest fires, crystal growth, etc.

Here are some examples: http://neekatave.com/ca/examples/ffire/index.php

You will see links in there to [Star Logo](http://education.mit.edu/starlogo/), which is an educational MIT project that has a bunch more examples (warning, you may lose a lot of time clicking around there :)